# Remove Square Bracket From Array Key PHP

Tags: php, arrays, highcharts

I'm needing some help with an array. I know this is more than likely a simple solution, but I'm new so I apologize! I've been stuck on this for a while.

This is the current array that I've got:

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 2 [2] => 5 [3] => 2 )
```

I need the array to look like this:

```
Array ( 0 => 3, 1 => 2, 2 => 5, 3 => 2 )
```

I'm trying to pass this information to HighCharts and it won't accept the array in the format I currently have.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Then iterate over the array and print in the wanted format - problem where?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work

```
// your array according to your question
$someArray = array();
$someArray[0] = 3;
$someArray[1] = 2;
$someArray[2] = 5;
$someArray[3] = 2;

// begin string output
$toHighCharts = 'Array(';

// loop through current array items
foreach($someArray as $k=>$v)
{
    // append string with desired format
    $toHghCharts.= $k.'=>'.$v.',';
}

// remove trailing comma
$toHighCharts = substr($toHighCharts, 0, -1);

// end string output
$toHghCharts.= ')';

// output string output
echo $toHighCharts;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I'm getting this error... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' ... pointing to the $k=$v in the foreach.

Comment: It's `$k=>$v` and not just `$k=$v`. Notice the `>` sign

Answer (score -2):

have you tried to convert the Array to a JavaScript Array with jsonencode?

For example:

```
var jsarray= <?php echo json_encode($phparray); ?>;
```

Comment: @JustinE If you look at their example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/) then user3207478 might actually have something useful here, maybe

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I still think your solution is a cleaner solution.

Comment: @JustinE I appreciate it but maybe OP isn't even sure of what they need especially if they haven't read the docs. Also it is absolutely baffling how many people don't know about `json_encode()` when using AJAX so spread the word lol =)

Comment: I really think, that using my method and then pass "jsarray" to highcharts should work well. its just one line of code instead of an php conversion. But I am sure, that MonkeyZeus's solution works great as well.

Comment: I honestly think your code is correct in this situation so that's why I gave you a +1. If you look at HighCharts you will see it expects an array for the data element that looks like this `data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]` so if OP was to do `echo 'data: '.json_encode(array(7.0,6.9,9.5,14.5,'etc'));` then they would get the exact output expected granted they maintain a regular numeric and ordered array.